# invalid free of memory on other thread's stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, valgrind, shared-ptr

I am trying to interrupt threads using shared memory properly, but it is not that simple. I am using Boost.lockfree and Boost.Thread. Here are the classes I have created:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Parameters_parser> sh_params_t;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Shared_objects> sh_obj_t;
class Abstract_thread {
    public:
        Abstract_thread(sh_params_t params, sh_obj_t sh_obj): 
            params(params), sh_obj(sh_obj) {}
        virtual ~Abstract_thread() = 0;
        virtual void launch() = 0;
     protected:
        /** The shared parameters of the execution. */
        sh_params_t params; 
        /** The Shared_objects containing all queues. */
        sh_obj_t sh_obj;
};
 inline Abstract_thread::~Abstract_thread(){
    cout << "Abstract_thread destructor with params: "
        << params.use_count() << " and sh_obj: " << 
        sh_obj.use_count() << endl;
}
class Interface_sniffer : public Abstract_thread {
    Interface_sniffer(sh_params_t params, sh_obj_t sh_obj): 
        Abstract_thread(params, sh_obj) {}
    ~Interface_sniffer(){
        cout << "Good bye from Interface_sniffer1 !" << endl;
     }
    void launch(){
        try {
            while(true)
                interruption_point();
         } catch(thread_interrupted const& e) {
             disable_interruption di;
             delete this;
         }
    }
};
```

Then, in the main:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sh_obj_t sh_obj = std::make_shared<Shared_objects>();
    sh_params_t params = std::make_shared<Parameters_parser>();
    Interface_sniffer sniffer1(params, sh_obj);
    boost::thread t1(bind(&Interface_sniffer::launch, &sniffer1));
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(5));
    cout << "trying to stop 1" << endl;
    t1.interrupt();
    t1.join();
}
```

`Parameters_parser` and `Shared_objects` are basic classes, containing fields that are only read by my threads, or with boost::lockfree::queue, that should not be the problem.

So when I run it, valgrind tells me:

```
trying to stop 1
Good bye from Interface_sniffer1 !
Abstract_thread destructor with params: 2 and sh_obj: 2
==2095== Thread 2:
==2095== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2095==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2095==    by 0x41A1C1: Interface_sniffer::~Interface_sniffer() (interface_sniffer.cpp:34)
==2095==    by 0x41A6DC: Interface_sniffer::launch() (interface_sniffer.cpp:69)
==2095==    by 0x44D1E8: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Interface_sniffer::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Interface_sniffer*) const (in somewhere)
==2095==    by 0x44D162: void std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Interface_sniffer::*)()> (Interface_sniffer*)>::__call<void, , 0ul>(std::tuple<>&&, std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (in somewhere)
==2095==    by 0x44D115: void std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Interface_sniffer::*)()> (Interface_sniffer*)>::operator()<, void>() (in somewhere)
==2095==    by 0x44CB9B: boost::detail::thread_data<std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Interface_sniffer::*)()> (Interface_sniffer*)> >::run() (thread.hpp:116)
==2095==    by 0x50C95D4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0)
==2095==    by 0x604D6B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==2095==    by 0x636A3DC: clone (clone.S:109)
==2095==  Address 0xfff000240 is on thread 1's stack
==2095==  in frame #3, created by main (main.cpp:23)
==2095==
```

So it pretends that I am deleting something located on the main thread's stack (I assume `params` and `sh_obj`), but it is not true since the object pointed by the shared_ptr is on the heap. What can I do ? Should I pass a `shared_ptr<>*` to my threads, and call `params->reset()` and `sh_obj->reset()` manually in the destructor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interface_sniffer` contains this code:

```
delete this;
```

And `main()` contains this code:

```
Interface_sniffer sniffer1(params, sh_obj);
```

So you are deleting a stack-allocated object, exactly as valgrind says.  This is undefined behavior.

Since `delete this` is very unusual (though sometimes valid and even useful), it would be a good idea to reconsider why and if you need it.  It isn't obvious from your code that you do need it.